# Set password using Saltstack mysql-formula?

Tags: salt-stack

I'm using the [SaltStack mysql-formula](https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/mysql-formula) and the defaults work just fine except for the root password.

Rather than try the pillar I thought this should work:

```
sudo salt 'ip-172-31-20-106.ec2.internal' state.sls mysql pillar="{'mysql:server:root_password':'Password'}" >
```

But no joy. I hacked on `debconfmod.py` to display the password but no luck there.

Should this work and if so how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I screwed-up the yml conversion into json.

The pillar yml is

```
mysql:
  server:
    root_password: 'somepass'
```

So the pillar json should be

```
pillar="{'mysql':{'server':{'root_password':'somepass'}}}"
```

Now everything works as it should.